# How to refresh select2 dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-select2

How to refresh select2 dropdown after refresh of page? For example, my dropdown has options:

```
option1 
option2
option3
```

When I open a page, default option is `option1`. When I choose `option2` and then refresh page, there is still `option2` as selected, not `option1`. How can I fix it? I noticed the problem only on Firefox, on Chrome it works fine.

My code:

```
(function ($) {
    var phone_category = document.querySelector("#block-phonesandhours-block > div.phonelist > select");
    var phone_items = document.querySelectorAll("#block-phonesandhours-block > div.phonelist > .items > div");

    $(phone_category).on("change", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selection = $(this).val();
        selection = selection.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

        $(phone_items).each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('class') == selection) {
                $(this).css("display","block");
            } else {
                $(this).css("display","none");
            }
        });
    });

    var hour_category = document.querySelector("#block-phonesandhours-block > div.hourlist > select");
    var hour_items = document.querySelectorAll("#block-phonesandhours-block > div.hourlist > .items > div");

    $(hour_category).on("change", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selection = $(this).val();
        selection = selection.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

        $(hour_items).each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('class') == selection) {
                $(this).css("display","block");
            } else {
                $(this).css("display","none");
            }
        });
    });


    $(hour_category).select2({
        containerCssClass: "wrap",
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
        dropdownPosition: 'below'
    });

    $(phone_category).select2({
        containerCssClass: "wrap",
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
        dropdownPosition: 'below'
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I'm not sure Select2 should remember the settings but please post your code, without it we can't tell if you have an error in your code.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I posted my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$(phone_category).val(value);
$(phone_category).trigger('change');
```

where `value` is the value of option you want to set.
hope this help! :)

Comment: The issue doing this is that is triggers any function that listens for the change event, hoping to find a way around this...

Comment: Looking at the docs, I used this function instead in order that each time I programatically set the value of the select, it doesnt then trigger any function listenting for the generic change event. 

$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  // Do something
});

Answer (score 2):

try this!
It will trigger  'change' event on document ready. plase it after you define you evet handlers.

```
    $(SELECTOR).trigger('change');


this code!

    (function ($) {
    var phone_category = document.querySelector("#block-phonesandhours-block > div.phonelist > select");
    var phone_items = document.querySelectorAll("#block-phonesandhours-block > div.phonelist > .items > div");

    $(phone_category).on("change", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selection = $(this).val();
        selection = selection.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

        $(phone_items).each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('class') == selection) {
                $(this).css("display","block");
            } else {
                $(this).css("display","none");
            }
        });
    });

    var hour_category = document.querySelector("#block-phonesandhours-block > div.hourlist > select");
    var hour_items = document.querySelectorAll("#block-phonesandhours-block > div.hourlist > .items > div");

    $(hour_category).on("change", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selection = $(this).val();
        selection = selection.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

        $(hour_items).each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('class') == selection) {
                $(this).css("display","block");
            } else {
                $(this).css("display","none");
            }
        });
    });


    $(hour_category).select2({
        containerCssClass: "wrap",
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
        dropdownPosition: 'below'
    }).trigger('change');

    $(phone_category).select2({
        containerCssClass: "wrap",
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
        dropdownPosition: 'below'
    }).trigger('change');
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help :(

Answer (score -1):

I guess there is problem in cache memory of browser. Install Extension for clear cache data. 
For example you can use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clearcache/) extension 

Do refresh using this extension.